# Can I re-sign a 3rd party assembly?

Tags: .net, assembly-signing, corflags

I have a project, which is intended to be run under x86 platform, but I have a 3rd party assembly which gives me a `BadImageFormatException`.
I could use **corflags** utility to set the **32BIT** flag, but then I'll have to resign the assembly.
Will this be legal?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run application the hosting process in a 32 bit. If that is not possible or a  requirement you should also deal with the implications of licensing on your 3rd party assembly.

Some open source licenses allows you to make changes to the assemblies including strong signing but you have to share the changes to the code or binaries. Other licenses don't care what you do with the code and assemblies as long as you mention them in the documentation or license.

With "commercial" 3rd party assemblies you probably will be violating the license if you re-sign the assembly. I'd suggest you to contact them and ask them for the signed assemblies.